# Binsary Search (BSEARCH1)

Tags: python

I was going through [this](https://www.spoj.com/problems/BSEARCH1/) problem on SPOJ.
It is a problem about binary search.
I tried to implement this in python:

```
x,yu= input().split()
bu=int(yu)
y=int(yu)
array=input().split()
while y>0:
  qquery=input()
  y=y-1
query=int(qquery)
b= int(x)
left=1
right= b

while left <= right and bu>0:

 pmid=((right+left)/2-1)
 mid=int(pmid)

 fir=array[mid]

 fire=int(fir)
 if fire== query:
   bu=bu-1
 if query < fire:
   left=mid+1
 else :
   right=mid-1
```

this is the input:

```
5 4
2 4 7 7 9
7
10 
4
2
```

I am getting an infinite loop with 3.
I have been stuck on this problem for a long time. I would really like someone to point out my mistake, the solution and the explanation.
Thank you!!

Comment: Infinite loop with 3 ***what?*** Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You have `bu=int(yu)` and `y=int(yu)`. Do you really want to do that? BTW, Stack Overflow questions must be self-contained. Links can be used for supporting info, but the question needs to make sense without the link. So you need to copy the relevant SPOJ information into your question.

Comment: Sorry for that .

Comment: By the way, binary search requires one very crucial thing about the collection you search through. Are you sure that the required property is true for your input? And if you don't know which property I'm talking about, then I suggest you do some research.

Comment: what I meant was that I was getting an infinite loop of the number 3.

Comment: You read a *lot* of input, since you don't provide *all* input you give then it's impossible for us to debug your code (which you really should [learn how to do](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) yourself first).

Comment: yes it is sorted

Comment: I tried to do it..... i have linked the problem....the input is provided there..... I will update my question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if you're looking for the binary search algorithm.

```
def binary_search(seq, t):
    min = 0
    max = len(seq) - 1
    while True:
        if max < min:
            return -1
        m = (min + max) // 2
        if seq[m] < t:
            min = m + 1
        elif seq[m] > t:
            max = m - 1
        else:
           return m
seq = [1, 2, 3, 4]
t = 2
binary_search(seq, t)
```

Comment: @Abhijith your question is not clear can you elaborate more

Comment: The [problem statement](https://www.spoj.com/problems/BSEARCH1/) requires the program to return the index of the first occurrence of a match. The code in this answer does not satisfy that requirement.